# Recuva for OS X?

Tags: filesystem, file-recovery

I'm looking for a file recovery utility for OS X, like Recuva for Windows. (Assuming Time Machine wasn't configured) Is there anything similar?

Answer (score 1):

I have used a product called [Disk Drill](http://www.cleverfiles.com/)

I personally successfully made good use of this product about a month ago when a simple mistake caused me to erase a drive I had no intention of erasing.  Basically, I added the drive I used to back up all my files as part of my CoreStorage for a DIY fusion drive.  So, I didn't just delete the files, I deleted the entire portion.

While I had most things backed up, I had several files that only existed on that drive.  I was able to recover every one of them.